# Changing style in ModelBuilder?

Tags: qgis, modelbuilder

Is it possible to have the output features of a model have a specific visual style? The features come out in a random assortment of colors and very small. Is there a tool for this? or any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to accomplish this.

In ArcMap load the layer in question and edit the symbology of the layer to your desired results.  Then click ‘Save As’ in the Symbol Selector window and Name the symbology exactly the same name as the data layer.  Now whenever that data layer is loaded in to ArcMap it will acquire the symbology with the same name.

The second way is to assign the symbology you want for the data layer in ArcMap, then right click the data layer and click ‘Save as Layer File’.  In Model builder right click the output feature class box, click properties, click ‘Layer Symbology’ tab and enter the pathname for the layer file for that specific data layer.

Comment: I think your second option is the preferred method when symbolizing output from a tool run in modelbuilder.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am working in QGIS. Will this still work? I have found that model builder in QGIS is less intuitive than arc

Answer (score 2):

Yes, atleast with QGIS 2.6.1. In the *Processing Toolbox*, right-click your model and select the **Edit rendering styles for outputs**:

[image: Model option for output style]

Then locate your style file:

[image: Locate style file]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use "Set Layer Style" from within the Model Builder, nowadays.

EDIT:
sure, here is the Set Layer Style in context and the inner dialog.
I am using it to set the style of a layer from a geopackage that i create within the same model. (unfortunately, i needed to set the style twice for each layer - once to get the style into the geopackage and once to get the style onto the layer when adding to the current project)
[image: Set Layer Style in context]
[image: dialog for set style]

Comment: Could you elaborate more with a screenshot?

Comment: sure @GforGIS... edited the answer, helpful?